# Access DOM element that is inserted after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My problem is basically quite simple.

After the page has been loaded some elements are added dynamically. I don't seem to be able to access those elements using normal jquery selectors.

Comment: can we see your code and how it is being added and btw welcometo stackoverflow !

Comment: dont get why people -2 the guy, obviously he is new in here :) give him a chance. @Jonas, you have to understand the flow of your script, so once the document has loaded, u are adding dynamic script using ajax? if so then on success you can select using jquery, otherwise basically you need to select them after they exist not before they exist, further more read about `.live()` http://api.jquery.com/live/ or maybe `.delegate()` http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ so they are done on the fly

Comment: I hate it when you ask a question and minutes later you find the answer. The JQuery .live() function is just what I need. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: It's a long time ago, but if you dislike your own question, you can delete it.

Comment: It was a stupid RTFM question. I can't delete it, because this question has anwer attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to do this, I use livequery. Livequery, basically, allows you to bind events to elements even before they are in the DOM. [Have a look](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), I'm pretty sure that's what you need! : )

Answer (score 0):

maybe .live() could be helpful: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thats what the op had figured out 5 minutes before you poste

Comment: LOL sure anytime ; ^ ) if its any consolation it costs me a point too